# rails .order method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

For some reason, the order method is not working in my code.  If I do in a model:

```
def apple
    @tasks_array = self.tasks.to_a
end
```

With the code above, an array is returned.  But if I do:

```
def apple
    @tasks_array = self.tasks.order('order_number').to_a
end
```

then

```
[]
```

is returned.  Here is the array that should be returned and that gets returned with the first block of code I wrote:

```
[#<Task id: 145, title: "task 1", content: "", created_at: "2013-12-18 18:44:31",
   updated_at: "2013-12-18 20:21:11", schedule_id: 79, amount: nil, 
   time_frame: "2013-12-19 15:00:00", state: "complete", denied: 3,
   order_number: 0>, #<Task id: 146, title: "Task 2", content: "",
   created_at: "2013-12-18 18:44:31", updated_at: "2013-12-18 20:24:06",
   schedule_id: 79, amount: nil, time_frame: "2013-12-27 10:00:00",
   state: "complete", denied: 1, order_number: 1>]
```

I have also tried taking out .to_a but it still does not work.

Comment: you can't order by nil values, order_number is nil in the array you have shown

Comment: I posted the wrong array to stack overflow.  The values are not nil.  I edited the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only explanation I can think of for this behavior is that:

- `self` has yet to be saved, or
- the task records do not exist in the database at the time this statement is executed
- the task records are no longer associated with self

but the value of `tasks` remains cached. `order` involves a SQL query, so it requires that the database be accessed.

The evidence for this would be that you see a SQL query echoed to the console only for the case of `order` being used.

As an alternative, you case use `Enumerable#sort_by` as follows:

```
self.tasks.sort_by {|task| task.order_id}
```

Comment: OH.  That makes sense.  It wouldn't be in the db because this is happening in a validation.  Do you know how to order an array thats not in the database?

Comment: You can use `sort` or `sort_by` from `Enumerable`

Comment: How would you do that?  I'm looking through the documentation and I can't figure out how to make it sort by order_number

Answer (score -3):

You need to specify either ascending or descending order in your ActiveRecord query.

Try:

```
self.task.order('order_number ASC').to_a
```

or

```
self.task.order('order_number DESC').to_a
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it did not work.  Also, I'm not the person who voted down this answer.

Comment: `ASC` and `DESC` are optional and `ASC` is assumed if neither is present.